# Python app not able to access from azure app services

Tags: python-3.x, azure-web-app-service

I have deployed a Python app to Azure app service (OS: Linux, Python) from Visual Studio Code. I can able to see the files in the `wwwroot` folder as well as in the app service, but when I am trying to access the app service by URL, the login page not displayed. Please refer to the code below:

```py
from flask import *

app=Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def welcome():
    return render_template("login_post.html")

"""using POST request method"""
@app.route('/login',methods=["POST"])
def login():
    uname=request.form["uname"]
    password=request.form["pass"]

    if uname=="shannu" and password=="guru":
        return "Welcome %s"%uname
    
if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run()
```

Refer to the screenshot for files under `wwwroot` folder (in app service):
[Index of /wwwroot/ directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HCjMo.png)

Not sure is there anything am I missing here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you accept it as answer ? Which can help more forum users, tks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need add startup command.

```
gunicorn --bind=0.0.0.0 --timeout 600 app:app
```

Offical doc:

[Flask app--Startup command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-language-python#flask-app)

## Suggestion

If this command not useful to you, it is recommand you deploy your flask app by vscode.

[image]

[image]

**You will find azure web app will auto generate `gunicorn` command for 'app:app'.**

[image]